# Python Kivy library installation on Ubuntu OS got dependency errors

Tags: python, ubuntu, kivy

I'm trying to convert my Python file to APK file on virtual machine(Ubuntu OS) but at first I have to install Kivy library on Ubuntu. In the Udemy video that I watch, I must only do 1 thing:

- `bash kivy-buildozer-installer.sh`

When I run this, everything goes well until here:

[image]
After that I got more than 100 lines of errors. This is a part of them:

[image]
I tried also

- `pip install kivy`
- `pip3 install kivy`
- `sudo pip install kivy`

and they got the same error with `bash kivy-buildozer-installer.sh`.

I don't know what to do else.

Comment: Can you mention python version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kivy wheel is not yet available for python 3.8
This issue is mentioned in [github issues](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6563#issuecomment-560039155)
You can still install it using

```
pip install kivy[base] kivy_examples --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems too when I tried to install it your way but `sudo apt install python3-kivy` worked for me. I advise you to try that.